# ¿Por qué en Java DateFormatSymbols.getShortWeekdays() tiene un día en blanco?

Tags: java, date, localización

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
String[] expected = DateFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.getDefault()).getShortWeekdays();
System.out.println("expect:" + Arrays.toString(expected));
```

Increíblemente para mí su salida es:

> expect:[, Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat]

Es decir el primer elemento es `""`. Y me ha entrado la curiosidad de saber a qué se debe:

- Que haya 8 días en vez de 7 en la semana
- Que un día no tenga nombre
- Que lo hayan puesto de primero

Sé que más que un problema es una curiosidad, pero pues de todo se aprende.
Salu2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lees [la documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html#getShortWeekdays()), verás que dice lo siguiente sobre el return de `getShortWeekdays()`:

> **Return**
>
> the short weekday strings. Use `Calendar.SUNDAY`, `Calendar.MONDAY`,
>   etc. to index the result array.

O sea, `getShortWeekdays()` usa `Calendar` para indexar el array resultante. Es decir, los arrays naturales en Java (tu objeto `expected` lo es) tienen como primer índice `0`, mientras que `getShortWeekdays()` usa `Calendar`, empieza a indexar los días partiendo de `1`.

Si remueves el primer elemento de `expected` entonces tu array quedará de la manera esperada:

```
String[] expected = DateFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.getDefault()).getShortWeekdays();
//Remover primer elemento
expected = Arrays.copyOfRange(expected, 1, expected.length);
System.out.println("expect:" + Arrays.toString(expected));
```

**Salida:**

```
expect:[Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat]
```

## Esto fue reportado como un bug, pero no lo es

Como dato curioso, este comportamiento del método [fue reportado como un bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4146173)  hace ya años. Pero la respuesta fue que no era bug, sino que el que devuelva 8 elementos en vez de 7 se debe a lo ya dicho en esta respuesta. Lo cierto es que no vendría mal algún tipo de método que permita obtener 7 elementos sin tener que quitar uno por la fuerza.

Si observas en el enlace, verás que el estado del reporte es `CLOSED`. Aunque es posible que ese reporte haya hecho posible que se ponga la nota que indica la documentación y que sirve como base documental a esta respuesta.

Comment: Eso mismo tenía hecho, pero es bueno saber que no hay alguna razón particular más que esa. Saludos.

Comment: @RuslanLópez como data curioso, esto fue reportado como un bug en 1998, pero no lo era. He agregado algo al respecto al final de la respuesta. Saludos.